# How to update a field in main table based on child tables in a form (with subform)?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two tables, one parent table named *Sales* which records transaction, and one child table named *SalesDetail* that records all items of each transaction.

Table *Sales* has the following fields: SalesID, Customer, CustomerInfo, VAT:

- SalesID: Primary Key
- Customer, Customer Info: other information fields
- VAT: VAT (tax) value of the transaction.

Table *SalesDetail* has the following fields: SalesDetailID, SalesMasterID, ItemName, UnitPrice, Qty, Amount, booVAT:

- SalesDetailID: Primary Key
- SalesMasterID: lookup field toward the primary key SalesID of the parent table *Sales*
- ItemName, UnitPrice, Qty: Item name, unit price (VAT excluded) and quantity of the selected item.
- Amount: the amount (price) of the selected item. A calculated field where Amount = UnitPrice * Qty
- booVAT: boolean

The moral of the story is, some items have VAT exemption (15%) for specific customers, that's why I cannot include the VAT directly into the price. Only those who are not exempt will have to pay the VAT, which will be checked in booVAT checkbox.

Each time the booVAT checkbox is ticked, 15% of Amount field in *SalesDetail* will be added to VAT field in *Sales*, and if it is unchecked, the same amount will be deduced.

Currently, I am having a Form named forSales where you can add or edit each *Sales* transaction, with a subform (datasheet) of *SalesDetail* subSalesDetail for all of items in each transaction. I also used some codes and macro to automatically update *Sales*.VAT, by using another Control of the parent Form (I named this control ctrVAT), with ctrVAT = Sum([subSalesDetail.Form!Amount]) * 0.15. However, when it comes to updating ctrVAT into *Sales*.VAT, I can't find any workaround it as I cannot catch the moment when ctrVAT is modified. Most event only fires for direct data modification, not with dynamic modification via calculated field nor VBA.

I also thought about using On Timer event, but using On Timer is not really elegant: having a macro constantly running in background can be a bit taxing on low-end computers.

Is there any way to work around this? I would like the calculation to be as automatic as possible to avoid human errors.

Comment: Are you sure, you need to deduct the VAT value if the checkbox is not checked? Or do you mean is should remain zero?

Comment: The checkbox's default state is No/Unchecked. When I check the checkbox, the VAT simply adds 15% of the Amount in its value. If I uncheck the checkbox again, obviously the VAT will subtract that 15% off.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of `ctrVAT` only changes when you update/add the Amount field in the SalesDetail form, you can use the AfterUpdate event of the subform.

In the AfterUpdate event of the SalesDetail subform you can do something like this:

`forSales!Vat = forSales!ctrVAT`

You will need to update the query on which your subform is based on, add a calculated field: `VATAmount: iif([booVAT], [Amount]*0.15, [Amount])`

Then update your control source of the `ctrVAT` to `=Sum([subSalesDetail.Form!VATAmount])`.

You'll probably need to add the `VATAmount` as a hidden field/column in the subform.

Comment: ctrVAT also gets modified from checking the booVAT checkbox. If you check it, that item will be included in VAT calculation; if not, it is excluded. To do this, I am using macro with AfterUpdate event on the checkbox booVAT (in the subform) to modify the ctrVAT (in the parent form).

AfterUpdate event of SalesDetail subform seems to have some conflict with AfterUpdate event of booVAT checkbox. It looks like the one of SalesDetail fires before that of the checkbox.

Comment: For some reason AfterUpdate event doesn't work when I press enter, only when I click out of the form.

As for `booVAT` belongs to the subform, though. My database can nitpick which item to be included in VAT calculation. In order to check `booVat` state I have to use macro, since control source doesn't work well with `iif` and `ctrVAT`

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can remove the event on the checkbox. Use a calculated field to calculate the VAT for the line item, and the form's (subform) AfterUpdate event to update the totals in your main form.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work out... First of all, `ctrVAT` is in the parent form, and me using `ctrVAT = Sum([subSalesDetail.Form!VATAmount])` just turns to error. I have to use a textbox `txtSumVAT` in the subform's Footer to calculate the sum first, then extract that `txtSumVAT` to the parent form's `ctrVAT`. Anyhow, each time the AfterUpdate fires, `ctrVAT` "updates" the second-last modification, and not the last modification.

Comment: Example, I have three records in `SalesDetail`. I modify the first record, jump to the next record, but `ctrVAT` does not change. I modify the second record, jump to the third record, then `ctrVAT` changes, but with the modification of the first record, not with the latest one (in the second record).

Comment: why don't you just build a query to calculate the total VAT per SalesId on the SalesDetail table, and use a DLookup to get and update the value in to Sales.Vat. This would be in my opinion the easiest and safest way to get the correct calculation. You would still use the afterupdate event in the subform.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Using query to calculate sum did not pass my mind at all. However, AfterUpdate event in the subform does not work at all, even if I press Tab, Enter, or pass to the next record.